# A definitive example of a simple conversion from Word files to PDF format using documents4j, please?

Tags: java, pdf, docx, documents4j

I have a simple Word file and I'd like to convert it to PDF using the `documents4j` api. Been searching for a few hours, but haven't found out how to go about writing the code. I just need a basic working code.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve this problem? If you have, please edit your question to include your code and research to show what hasn't worked for you. If you haven't, you should attempt to solve it yourself first and then post the code and research here. It makes your question easier for others to answer too!

Answer (score 5):

Add required dependencies in pom.xml

i.e,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>documents4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>       

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>documents4j-util-conversion</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>documents4j-transformer</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>documents4j-util-all</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>documents4j-local</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>documents4j-local-demo</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

And use following code snippet in order to convert document into PDF.
In below example, I`m converting RTF file to PDF.

```
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\PDF\\RichText1.rtf"));
        IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
                                             .baseFolder(new File("C:\\PDF\\"))
                                             .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                             .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                             .build();

        Future<Boolean> conversion = converter
                                        .convert(in).as(DocumentType.RTF)
                                        .to(bo).as(DocumentType.PDF)
                                        .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
                                        .schedule();
```

So your required converted file will be stored into ByteArrayOutputStream  object (bo) here.

Answer (score 0):

The example presented in this article didn't work for me.
This one did:

POM FILE:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-util-conversion</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-transformer</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-util-all</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-local</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-util-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.documents4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>documents4j-transformer-msoffice-word</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>23.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And java file:

```
import com.documents4j.api.DocumentType;
import com.documents4j.api.IConverter;
import com.documents4j.job.LocalConverter;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 *
 * @author Neon/Jan Madle
 */
public class NewMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +"out.rtf"));
    IConverter converter = LocalConverter.builder()
            .baseFolder(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator +"test"))
            .workerPool(20, 25, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .processTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    Future<Boolean> conversion = converter
            .convert(in).as(DocumentType.RTF)
            .to(bo).as(DocumentType.PDF)
            .prioritizeWith(1000) // optional
            .schedule();
    conversion.get();
    try (OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("out.pdf")) {
        bo.writeTo(outputStream);
    }
    in.close();
    bo.close();
}
}
```